# Web Crawling Using Node js

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, mean-stack, cheerio

I am scraping medium.com. I am trying to display all the links present on the website.

```
var url="https://medium.com/";

    request(url,function(error,response,html){

        if(!error && response.statusCode==200){

            var $=cheerio.load(html);

            var json={content:"",link:""};
            var jsonObjects=[];

            var links=$('a');
            //console.log(links);
            $(links).each(function(i,link){
                json.content=$(link).text();
                json.link=$(link).attr('href');
                jsonObjects.push(json);
            });


        }

        fs.writeFile('Links.json',JSON.stringify(jsonObjects,null,4),function(err){
            if(!err){
                res.send("File written successfully!!!!")
            }
        })

    })
```

When I am using this code, only one link is showing up again an again in Links.json file.

> [
>       {
>           "content": "About",
>           "link": "https://about.medium.com"
>       },
>       {
>           "content": "About",
>           "link": "https://about.medium.com"
>       },
>       {
>           "content": "About",
>           "link": "https://about.medium.com"
>       },
>       {
>           "content": "About",
>           "link": "https://about.medium.com"
>       },
>       {
>           "content": "About",
>           "link": "https://about.medium.com"
>       },
>       {
>           "content": "About",
>           "link": "https://about.medium.com"
>       },
>       {
>           "content": "About",
>           "link": "https://about.medium.com"
>       },
>       {

I have tried everything but not getting even the links of main page of medium.com
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you keep on editing the same object and pushing it into the array again and again.

```
var json={content:"",link:""};
```

should be inside your `each` loop.

```
var url="https://medium.com/";

    request(url,function(error,response,html){

        if(!error && response.statusCode==200){

            var $=cheerio.load(html);
            var jsonObjects=[];

            var links=$('a');
            //console.log(links);
            $(links).each(function(i,link){
                var content = $(link).text();
                var link = $(link).attr('href');
                jsonObjects.push({ content: content, link: link });
            });


        }

        fs.writeFile('Links.json',JSON.stringify(jsonObjects,null,4),function(err){
            if(!err){
                res.send("File written successfully!!!!")
            }
        })

    })
```